# iPhone+Safari+PWA: How to avoid Push notification prompting can only be done from a user gesture

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

I would like to use Fireabase messaging service to notify Web Application with PWA in Safari(iPhone).
However, when I try to get the FCM Token during screen initialization, I get the following error.

`Notification prompting can only be done from a user gesture.`

[getToken source that is Throwing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKRch.png)

The user cannot set the user to allow notifications because the dialog to set notifications is not displayed.

- Question 1: If I want to display the Dialog for notification permission again after starting with PWA, how can I configure it?
- Question 2: If I do not place the button to allow notification permission on the screen, is there any way to avoid the "Notification prompting can only be done from a user gesture." error?

Thanks